# Countably infinite sequence of sets in finite $\mathcal{P}(S)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In a theorem showing that a power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is a sigma-algebra on proofwiki.org, there is the following part:

> Let $S$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{P}(S)$ be its power set.
>
> [...]
>
> Let $\langle A_i \rangle$ be a **countably infinite sequence** of sets in $\mathcal{P}(S)$
>
> [...]

But what if $S$ is finite? Then its power set is also finite, so I'm confused whether it makes sense to speak about **countably infinite sequence** on a finite set.

Comment: Sets could repeat in the sequence.

Comment: Is the constant sequence $\langle x_i=0\mid i\in\Bbb N\rangle$ not a sequence? Is its length not $\omega$ (the length of the natural numbers as an ordered set)?

Comment: "Sets could repeat in the sequence." That's an interesting solution. Any `standard' reference mentioning it? (didn't find it on proofwiki)

Comment: Asaf Karagila: I don't know the answers to these questions, neither how it relates to the OP question, I'm sorry.

Comment: John, I think it might be the case that you are conflating "the sequence $(A_i)$ is countably infinite" and "the image of the sequence $(A_i)$ is countably infinite"/"the set of points in the sequence is c. infinite". The former just means "there are countably infinitely many indices in the sequence/the sequence is infinitely long", or in other words "it's a sequence in the sense of [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sequence#Definition)". Such a sequence may have repeating elements, and indeed it may only consist of finitely many different elements (repeated infinitely often)!

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen: Thank you! It means that one can create a) a countably infinite sequence from a **countably infinite set** and b) a countably infinite sequence from a **finite** set by just repeating the terms. The a) case is generic enough (everything is countably inifinite), and b) is a special case to have just one simple definition. Right?